# "associated types may not be referenced here"

Tags: rust

Can someone explain why this code fails to compile?

```
#![feature(associated_types)]

trait Wub {
    type Zoop;
}

trait Flim: Wub {
}
```

I get the error:

```
qqq.rs:7:13: 7:16 error: associated types may not be referenced here
qqq.rs:7 trait Flim: Wub {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug, I filed [#18996](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18996). Associated items are very raw at the moment, issue [#17307](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/17307) summarises how much there is to go.